# Back up the restore partition and boot loader?

Tags: boot-loader

Got a new workstation replacement laptop and it came with XP Pro. I'm going to use it to test Windows 7 and Ubuntu, but it may need to go back to XP later on.

It has the recovery option at boot and a 10GB partition at the end of the disk for the pre-installed image. I'm assuming that the "Press F11 for recovery" is just a replacement bootloader that points to either the XP partition or the recovery one.

Ubuntu is unable to resize the XP partition so I can't do dual boot, and it would blow away the exiting boot loader.

So...

How would you go about backing up the recovery boot loader and partition?

Comment: Boot with Knoppix

Backup - dd if=/dev/(h or s)da of=mbr.backup bs=512 count=1
Restore - dd if=mbr.backup of=/dev/(h or s)da bs=512 count=1

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Snapshot (www.drivesnapshot.de). This can image all the partitions and burn them back to disk later.

Doesn't the laptop come with an installation CD? If not you can probably download it from the manufacturers web site.

JR

Comment: It came with a CD. I doubt it would restore the restore partition though. Need to backup anyway before I can find out.